# Birational map from even to odd degree curve. What is the image of one of infinity points?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, birational-geometry, hyperelliptic-curves

Suppose I have a curve $C_1$ determined by $C_1: y^2 = (x+a)(f_{2g+1} x^{2g+1} + \dots + f_0)$. It has even degree polynomial of $x$ on the right side. I want to consider its image under birational map $X = 1/(x + a),\ Y = y/(x+a)^{g+1}$. It should be the curve $C_2: Y^2 = h_{2g+1} X^{2g+1} + \dots + h_0$ which has odd degree polynomial on the right side.

It is easy to calculate image of arbitrary point of $C_1$ except one of infinity points.

How can I calculate image of $P_{\infty_1}$ and $P_{\infty_2}$ (points at infinity) under that birational map? Is it possible to do using weighted projective model?